macOS Process Mobileassetupdaterd Hogging CPU
A process named Mobileassetupdaterd owned by the user _accessoryupc, hogs 35% of CPU.
It's associated with a file named MobileAssetUpdater at:
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileAssetUpdater.framework/MobileAssetUpdater
Which is a 35 byte alias pointing to the executable at:
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileAccessoryUpdater.framework/Support/accessoryupdaterd
Which is consistently relaunches using this Plist:
/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.accessoryupdaterd.plist
I tried unloading the process with this command others have suggested:
sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.accessoryupdaterd.plist
But I just get the error: Unload failed: 5: Input/output error
So I'm just not a Terminal master.
I've also tried exhaustive searches at Apple, here at StackOverflow, and online to find a solution, with no luck.
I watch processes periodically, and it wasn't there until I Updated OS from Ventura to Sonoma 14.5.
Anyone have thoughts?
Running macOS Sonoma 14.5 on 2021 M1 MacBook Pro.
Thanks!
